# Understanding segfault information

Tags: c++, debugging, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to debug a segfault that happens when I run my program written in C++.

I am getting an  error of this sort when I run my program:

```
[1]    24926 segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./program
```

What I would like to know is what do the numbers written before the segfault indicate, i.e., what is `[1]` and what is `24926`?

Thank You

Comment: Could be stack depth and thread ID, but it's hard to be sure. which OS or debugging tool emitted this message?

Comment: Not what you asked but take a look at `gdb` segfault debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[1]` is the job ID number, and `24926` is the PID (process ID) of the program which crashed.

I'm assuming you're on a Unix-based system right now, as far as I know they're the only ones to use this format.
This isn't very meaningful information to help you solve your problem though, so you'd be better off opening another thread and share your code in the new one.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was looking for. I solved the segfault problem btw.